# Kinect v2 - SDK 2.0 Depth Stream in Delphi

Tags: delphi, kinect, depth

Did anybody managed to get an kinect v2 depth stream with delphi?
There only seem to exist sdk 1.5.2 headers (kinect gen. 1) here:
https://code.google.com/p/kinect-sdk-delphi/

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is a bit late but I managed to do this. I kind of cheated and made a C DLL that goes in between the Kinect20.lib and Delphi.

You can find my implementation here. 
https://github.com/ConroyBadger/DelphiKinect2Depth

A Win32 sample application is included along with the source.